# What hashing algorithm should I use?

Tags: php, passwords, hash

The PHP function `hash_algos()` gives me this list on my webserver:

```
[0] => md2
[1] => md4
[2] => md5
[3] => sha1
[4] => sha256
[5] => sha384
[6] => sha512
[7] => ripemd128
[8] => ripemd160
[9] => ripemd256
[10] => ripemd320
[11] => whirlpool
[12] => tiger128,3
[13] => tiger160,3
[14] => tiger192,3
[15] => tiger128,4
[16] => tiger160,4
[17] => tiger192,4
[18] => snefru
[19] => gost
[20] => adler32
[21] => crc32
[22] => crc32b
[23] => haval128,3
[24] => haval160,3
[25] => haval192,3
[26] => haval224,3
[27] => haval256,3
[28] => haval128,4
[29] => haval160,4
[30] => haval192,4
[31] => haval224,4
[32] => haval256,4
[33] => haval128,5
[34] => haval160,5
[35] => haval192,5
[36] => haval224,5
[37] => haval256,5
```

Which ones should I use for what and why? Especially, which one should I use for password hashing?

Comment: Just a quick comment... you can see the discussions of these algorithms on the php manuals/forums.

Answer (score 1):

**SHA256 or SHA384 for password hashing**. I've heard that some US organisations' policies disallow software components using SHA with higher bit length, but that depends.

Avoid MDx for hashing secure things like passwords if you can use SHA. See [Is MD5 really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768248/is-md5-really-that-bad)

CRCxx is for checksums, they're bad for hashes as their value range is much smaller.

The others, I don't know about their use-cases.

Comment: Rainbow tables are irrelevant to particular hashing algorithm. It seems you just don't understand what is it. It is *salt* what makes rainbow tables useless.

Comment: Yeah sorry, didn't think about it

Comment: -1 SHA fails at password hashing because it is **too fast and easy to parallelize**. See bcrypt, scrypt, and even PKDBF-2 for "correct" alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you should not use any of the above hashing algorithms directly. Since you are using PHP, you may consider **phpass** (used by WordPress, Drupal 7) http://www.openwall.com/phpass/.

There are many discussions in the PHP communities on this topic, so don't re-invent security.

1. http://drupal.org/node/29706
2. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/2394,

Answer (score -4):

Both md5 and sha1 are decent for password hashing. Unfortunately, they are still vulnerable to a dedicated attacker with rainbow tables, but a minimum password length requirement will alleviate that issue.

Comment: I sure would like to know why this got down voted. Have I missed something critical? How can I improve?

Comment: It was down-voted (again) for being wrong. MD5 and SHA1 fail at password hashing because they are **too fast and easy to parallelize**. See bcrypt, scrypt, and even PKDBF-2 for "correct" alternatives.

Comment: (MD5 fails for other reasons as well, too :D)